# jquery multiple select setting default value if only 1 is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let´s say i have multiple select dialog in a jquery mobile solution like this:

```
     <select name="fruitFilter" id=fruitFilter" multiple="multiple" data-native-menu="false">
          <option>Fruit choice</option>
          <option value="1">Choice1</option>
          <option value="2">Choice2</option>
          <option value="3">Choice3</option>
          <option value="4">Choice4</option>
          <option value="1234">All Fruits</option>
        </select>
```

I want choice 1-4 to be selectable individually but if I check "All Fruits" I want all selections to be marked(disabled to be correct) and un-ckecked 
Unselecting "All Fruits" would then enable choice 1-4 to be selectable again.

as of now I have all working and loading/saving to localstorage except from this ability to disable/enable all/individually

Anyone have any idea how this can be made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this?

```
var selAllValue = "1234",
    $fruitSelect = $('#fruitFilter'),
    $allOptions = $fruitSelect.children(), //get all options
    $selAllOption = $allOptions.filter('[value="' + selAllValue + '"]'); //Get the check all option

$fruitSelect.on('change', function () {
    var $this     = $(this),
        currSel   = ($this.val() || []).pop(), //get the last selected value.
        $options  = $allOptions, 
        flg       = (currSel === selAllValue);

    if (flg) { //if it is equal to alloption
       $options = $options.not($selAllOption).prop('selected', false); //unselect others and set $options to the new list
    }

    $options.prop('disabled', flg); //finally set the disable flag on $options. i.e disable flag will be set if current selection is alloption else just not disable all.

    $this.selectmenu('refresh'); //refresh select menu to take effect.

});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hummL/)**

Comment: You are My knight in shining armour! Tnx alot